# Interface gráfica com Tkinter atrasando meu código

Tags: python-3.x, loop, tkinter

Tô fazendo um scriptzinho pra automatizar algumas coisas no Windows só que um problema que encontrei é que pra fechar ele (depois de ter convertido pra executável com o **auto-py-to-exe**) tem que fazer mó trampo, indo no **Gerenciador de Tarefas** e procurando o processo por lá. Comecei a colocar uma interface gráfica pra poder exibir status e poder fechar o programa mais facilmente. O problema tá na função **mainloop()** da janela principal. Tenho que colocar muito código pra ser executado depois de abrir ela mas a função trava a execução do programa. Já procurei outra função que não tenha esse tipo de operação mas não achei. Poderiam me ajudar?

Exemplo do script:

```
from tkinter import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import os

def bt_click():
    exit()

window = Tk()
window.resizable(0,0)
window.title("WELCOME !")
window.geometry("680x450+320+150")
lb1 = Label(window,text="Executando...")
lb1.place(x=0,y=0)
bt1 = Button(window,text="Quit",width=25,command=bt_click)
bt1.place(x=250,y=140)
txt1 = Text(window,)
window.mainloop()

k = Controller()
time.sleep(9)
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    k.press('t')
    k.release('t')
    k.type('/plantar')
    k.press(Key.enter)
    k.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(87)
    k.press('t')
    k.release('t')
    k.type('/colher')
    k.press(Key.enter)
    k.release(Key.enter)
```

Comment: pelo oq posso deduzir, vc esta tentando usar um while(pegar as entradas de teclado) junto de um mainloop()?
ñ sei fazer direito, mas tem algo tipo event bind, onde vc pode passar a teclas pada determinadas tarefas

Comment: Na real minha dúvida é quanto ao mainloop() travar o programa e só executar a próxima ação se a janela da interface gráfica for fechada. O código que vêm depois poderia ser outro que o resultado seria o mesmo.

Comment: então mainloop é um loop infinito, o codigo vai repetir ate ele terminar, por isso recomendei o bind, pois vai permitir fazer entradas definidas de teclado mesmo durante o mainloop
caso ñ queira tentar o bind vc pode tentar chamar o main loop dessa forma: mainloop(n=1)

Comment: Estou mais acostumado com GTK, mas pelo que pude ver, falta chamar o comando destroy na função bt_click, de uma olhada neste exemplo https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html